# strftime doesn't show PM or AM

Tags: php, strftime

This is the code I use to get the date (in spanish):

```
$fecha = strftime("%d de %B, %Y, a las %l:%M %p");
```

and I get:

```
27 de julio, 2011, a las 7:10
```

So the question is, where is my PM (or AM)?

My application is running on Linux.

Comment: Are you running php on a Mac?

Answer (score 7):

Well,, the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) says

> Not all conversion specifiers may be supported by your C library, in which case they will not be supported by PHP's strftime(). Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, so your date

This could be your problem. In that case you could do something like this to get the AM/PM:

```
$time = time();
$fecha = strftime("%d de %B, %Y, a las %l:%M ", $time).(($time%86400) < 43200 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
```

**EDIT**:

This answer is assuming you want a UTC time string (if you want another timezone, you should also include the timezone in the string if you are storing it or sending it anywhere), and that your php.ini has `date.timezone` set to `UTC` . If you are not using UTC, you should compute an offset. [See @Soylent17's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39399086/772035).

Comment: This works, but it's the other way around 'PM' : 'AM'.
Thanks.

Comment: No, actually it's not, it's 'AM' : 'PM'. I just tested.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy It works in some circumstances. I think after midnight is when it gets messed up.

Comment: Usefull on windows systems! In MSDN documentation de strftime (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx), "%p" not function

Answer (score 6):

The question is old, but in case someone else needs it, it also happened to me.

It seems that the spanish locale has not implementation for %p, so make sure that your line is before the line setting the locale to spanish. Probably you will need to fraction your code like this.

```
 $hora = strftime(" a las %l:%M %p");
 $loc_sp = setlocale (LC_TIME,'es_ES');
 $fecha = strftime("%d de %B, %Y");
 echo $fecha.$hora;
```

Comment: your answer inspired my answer, check it! :D

Comment: After days of struggling with this issue, Your answer is the only one that solved my problem. Thank You!!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment to PaulPro's answer, so I'll just have to expand on it. When working with the timestamp directly, you will need to adjust for your timezone offset.  So where PaulPro put `$time%86400`, you need something like `($time+date('Z'))%86400`

```
$time = time();
$fecha = strftime("%d de %B, %Y, a las %l:%M ", $time).(($time+date('Z'))%86400 < 43200 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you on OSX? If so `%p` or `%P` [isn't supported](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Answer (score 2):

you can try using another value on `setlocale()`, because `es_MX` dont work for me but `es_CO` do the job, it has support for `%p` and `%P`, it depends on the server configuration :v

possible values list

- es_MX ~ México
- es_ES ~ España
- es_RA ~ Argentina
- es_CO ~ Colombia
- [complete list here](http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=857:mostrar-fecha-en-espanol-php-setlocale-strftime-formato-datedefault-timezone-set-ejemplos-cu00831b&catid=70:tutorial-basico-programador-web-php-desde-cero&Itemid=193)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @iyepes, I resolved to completely bypass the Locale if you have the site in multiple languages, %P or %p are both worthless in locales other than those in English I suppose, at least that's the case for Spanish

Separate %P or %p from the locale, if you have a while loop, set locale to en_US, extract times in en_US strftime including %P then set back to locale defined by user.

```
$day1 =  strtotime($row["day1"]);
$day2 = strtotime($row["day2"]);
$day3 = strtotime($row["day3"]);

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");

$time1 = strftime("%l:%M %P", $day1);
$time2 = strftime("%l:%M %P", $day2);
$time3 = strftime("%l:%M %P", $day3);

  setlocale(LC_ALL, $defined_locale);

$day1 - strftime("%d de %B, %Y, " $day1).$time1;
$day2 - strftime("%d de %B, %Y, " $day2).$time2;
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
function mystrftime($format, $time=null){
    if(!$time) $time = time();
    preg_match_all('/%[a-zA-Z]/', $format, $placeholders);
    foreach ($placeholders[0] as $placeholder){
        if(strftime($placeholder, $time)==''){
            $format = str_replace($placeholder, '%'.$placeholder, $format);
        }
    }   
    $format = strftime($format, $time);
    preg_match_all('/%[a-zA-Z]/', $format, $placeholders);
    $locale = setlocale('LC_TIME', '0');
    setlocale('LC_TIME', 'en_US.UTF8');
    foreach ($placeholders[0] as $placeholder){
        $format = str_replace($placeholder, strftime($placeholder, $time), $format);
    }   
    setlocale('LC_TIME', $locale);
    return $format;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and ugly

```
$date="2016-11-15 12:34";    
$fecha=strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y %l:%M", strtotime("$date")).date(' a', strtotime("$date"));
```

results in: martes, 15 de noviembre de 2016 12:34 pm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the locale is spelled the right way. For me, en_US.utf8 worked fine, en_US did not work at all. 
Try to check installed locales on unix machines by calling

```
locale -a
```

on the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to my question here when I figured out how to solve it.

This was my default setting for language.

```
// Set Default Timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
// Set Date Language -> Unix
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
// Set Date Language -> Windows
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
```

Then, I was trying to display the current date with AM and PM but it wasn't working.

```
echo strftime("%d de %b de %Y, %H:%M %p", strtotime($sqlDate);
```

This was showing an empty field because of the %p parameter. When I read AgelessEssence's comment I started to switch between these options:

- es_MX ~ México
- es_ES ~ España
- es_RA ~ Argentina
- es_CO ~ Colombia

None of them were working, while I was thinking I left this field empty and saved.

```
 // Set Date Language -> Windows
    setlocale(LC_TIME, '');
```

Then, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $formato = "%A, %e de %B de %Y, %I:%M:%S %p";
        // Comprobación para Windows para hallar y remplazar el
        // modificador %e adecuadamente
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
            $formato = preg_replace('#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%e#', '\1%#d', $formato);
        }
        $formato = preg_replace('#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%p#', '\1#p', $formato);
        $x = @strftime($formato);
        $y = date('A');
        $x = str_replace('#p', $y, $x);
```